# CSS li.before circle within coloured box just as li text

Tags: css

I might be going about this the wrong way, but what I'm trying to achieve is a list style horizental that links in with some js that changes the navigation from one tab to another. The tab headings should have a counter before the text within a css circle using radius and I've got this far.

What I can't seem to resolve is how to then place this circle within a box the same colour as the li text background and ensure it changes colour when hovered/selected.

Here's my code so far:

```
    OL.evotab {
        counter-reset:li;
        list-style: none;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        padding:0px;
    }

    OL.evotab LI {
        list-style:none;
        position:relative;
        display: inline;
        float:left;
        margin:0 0 6px 2em;
        padding:4px 8px;
    }
    ol.evotab > li:before {
content:counter(li); /* Use the counter as content */
counter-increment:li; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
/* Position and style the number */
position:absolute;
top:-2px;
left:-2em;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
width:2em;
/* Some space between the number and the content in browsers that support
   generated content but not positioning it (Camino 2 is one example) */
margin-right:8px;
padding:4px;
border-radius:50%;
color:#fff;
background:#666;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
text-align:center;
}
OL.evotab LI A {
background-color: #f8f8f8;
color: #28343d;
    text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
padding-bottom:30px;
border-bottom:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    }
    OL.evotab LI A.selected,
OL.evotab LI A:hover {
background-color: #f8f8f8;
color: #e51f38;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom:30px;
border-bottom: 5px solid #e51f38;
    }

    OL.evotab LI A:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gu36p/)**

Its a little difficult to see what you mean without any HTML....but have a look at the fiddle linked for an idea.

HTML

```
<a href='#'>This is an Item</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    background:grey;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
}
a:before {
    content:'7';
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    background:yellow;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 999px;
    left:-5px;
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:20px;
    height:20px;
}
a:hover, a:hover:before {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fiddle for the response - the html rather reads like a standard list: <div class="evolist">
        <ol class="evotab">
            <li><a href="#one">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#three">Third</a></li>
        </ol>
        </div><!--end of evolist!-->

Comment: Hmm, the above unfortunately doesn't resolve my issue. Does anyone else have any other ideas? I'm trying to refrain from using images as .before, much rather use CSS

Comment: It may help to edit your question with the HTML and CSS which relates specifically to what you're after, and better still a jsfiddle.net with what you have now